# pygame, smoothscale png image with alpha transparency channels - black edges

Tags: python, image, pygame, png

I have a problem with scaling images in pygame library. I have a scene and character loaded from large PNG assets. Those PNGs has alpha transparency (mostly on the edge).

For my game, i need to scale it down, but I am unable to get satisfying results. With scale, i get pixelated edges, with smoothscale, i get black line around my image.

Image is loaded with: `pygame.image.load(png_file).convert_alpha()`

When i use

- `pygame.transform.scale(img, (scaled_width, scaled_height))` i get pixelated result with OK alpha channels (example: [image: pixelated image])
- `pygame.transform.smoothscale(img, (scaled_width, scaled_height))` the result smoothness is perfect, but there is black edge, since the smoother function probably can't reflect the alpha channels. (example: )

[image: smoothscaled image but black edge]

I also tried some snippets i found here, but no success. (for example:

```
surface = pygame.Surface((scaled_width, scaled_height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
surface.blit(pygame.transform.smoothscale(img, (scaled_width, scaled_height)), (0, 0))
```

I also tried to make it 2x bigger with scale, and then smoothscale to predefined size, still, black edge.

I need to use png (content will be replacable by users), so svg is no option here (even though, as i saw, you convert svg to png anyway, so it might have the same problem). Am i missing something? Is there any effective way to resize png? For now, I have ~50 png images in scene, so i would like to avoid using external libraries (PIL, etc), but if its necessary, i will have to :(. Thanks for your suggestions.

another try, white edge:

```py
surface = pygame.Surface((scaled_width, scaled_height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
scaled_surface = pygame.transform.smoothscale(img, (scaled_width, scaled_height))
surface.blit(scaled_surface, (0, 0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED)
return surface
```

result:
[image: white edge]

Comment: The documentation for transform.scale states "This is a fast scale operation that does not sample the results."  That's probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Indeed, i read the documentation. Thats why I use smoothscale. But as I mentioned, I am unable to get smooth images with alpha transparency without the edge.

Answer (score 1):

When the image is scaled down, the color channels and the alpha channel are interpolated. So if the background of the image is RGBA=(0, 0, 0, 0), the interpolated color channels at the edge behave as if they were pre-multiplied with the alpha channel. Therefore, the flag [`pygame.BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) must be set when `blit`ing the image:

```py
surface = pygame.Surface((scaled_width, scaled_height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
scaled_surface = pygame.transform.smoothscale(img, (scaled_width, scaled_height)
surface.blit(scaled_surface, (0, 0), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED)
```

See also [Dark borders in cv2.blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977901/dark-borders-in-cv2-blur), [Surface alpha lost when converting pygame to cv2 to pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69888520/surface-alpha-lost-when-converting-pygame-to-cv2-to-pygame)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunatelly no success. Now i've got white edge, see my original post - added the image at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The images you linked are the same, and with no alpha channel, I guess it's a mistake ?

Whatever, about your issue, it's quite known is the field of resizing alpha images, and not proper to PyGame. Basically, alpha channels can be bullshited by interpolation from image resizing. Depending on the interpolation for example you can have zero-padding (which means that pixels on the borders have no neighbors to be interpolated with, and the algorithm just take some "zeros" instead...)

On my side for manipulating images (even within a PyGame app) I prefer OpenCV (`pip install opencv-python`) which gives a lot of liberty on the results. For instance, here is an example where you can resize RGB and alpha separatly, using interpolation on RGB, and no interpolation ("nearest") on the alpha :

```py
import cv2

path_in = "input.png"
path_out = "output.png"
img = cv2.imread(path_in, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
new_size = (640, 480)

# Compute alpha and rgb separately
rgb = cv2.resize(img[:,:,:3], new_size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
alpha = cv2.resize(img[:,:,3], new_size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

# Merge back alpha with rgb
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
rgba[:, :, 3] = alpha

# Save
cv2.imwrite(path_out, rgba)
```